# how to get the dynamic html element id value using HtmlCollections or Nodelist

Tags: javascript, nodelist, htmlcollection

**i was making the dynamic element by using innerhtml, but i did not get the element id dynamically.**

```
var videoWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrap');
   console.log(videoWrap)
```

**//console value**

```
HTMLCollection(1)
0: div#cardvideo_localstream.p-1.position-relative.videowrap
cardvideo_localstream: div#cardvideo_localstream.p-1.position-relative.videowrap
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: HTMLCollection
item: ƒ item()
length: (...)
namedItem: ƒ namedItem()
constructor: ƒ HTMLCollection()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "HTMLCollection"
get length: ƒ length()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

> i want to get the id value -> #cardvideo_localstream

Comment: do you mean that `document.getElementById('cardvideo_localstream')` doesn't return the element?

Comment: @Diego De Vita
  No, i want to using  tagname or class name to get the id value, because of id is a dynamic value, that changed on every time to refreshing the page. so do you have any idea's! and  Thanks for your supporting!

Comment: videoWrap[0].id will return the id of the first element in the videoWrap HTMLCollection. Is that what you meant to get? The question is very confused and hard to interpret.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita
  var videoWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('.videoWrap')[0].id;
   console.log(videoWrap)                                                                                                    
 i already tried this they have type error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id'))

Comment: when you use getElementsByClassName you don't need to use a css selector but just the name of the class. Maybe you just made a typo because you used it correctly in your main question. By the way as you stated there in your original question that part returned an HTMLCollection ... so now I'm surprised to hear that fetching the first element with [0] returns undefined. Are you sure??

Comment: @DiegoDeVita The class name  not in html page statically, it worked on javscript innerHTML.  so it cannot taken the id value.

Comment: the innerHTML gets translated in objects populating the dom... by the way you didn't address the issue I highlighted in my latest comment. You had to do this: `document.getElementsByClassName('videoWrap')[0]`! and see if it was still undefined or not. For sure not this `document.getElementsByClassName('.videoWrap')[0]`

Comment: Anyway instead of keep saying words why didn't you just share the piece of code creating that html code? this question has been alive for hours and still unresolved... ask yourself why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

- You can get dynamic **id** by retrieving tag-name or class-name as you prefer.
  But the structure should be fixed. You need to parse result of output(e.g property value) and get **id** wherever is located.
- In another way the output you give you can simply trim the string and get **id**.

But in both case the format/structure should be fix otherwise it'll break.

Comment: thanks for Your supporting!  please give some reference..

Comment: https://codepen.io/piyush-multiplexer/pen/wvyVoqG

Review this pen, i have added both ways.